# Mocking "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am trying to come up with a solution for the following scenario:

I have migrated a web app from forms auth, to OWIN+OAuth.

Now, there is also a mobile client app ( android ). The mobile client is authenticated against the web app, if everything goes well the server will respond with the user's data and it used to respond with 2 cookies as well, one been the session cookie ( never used, but its presence was checked on the client ) and the other one was the user's identity cookie. The mobile client validates that the user's data "look good" and it also checks for the presence of those 2 cookies in order to pass the login screen.

What i am trying to do right now is to keep the mobile app unaffected by the changes on the server, by supplying the user's data as needed after all the required checks, and then mocking the presence of the 2 cookies, so that i can avoid making any changes on the mobile apps ( avoid the need to compile and update the clients that is )

The code below is implemented in an API controller, and while the `.ASPXAUTH` cookie seems to work fine , the old `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie seems uncontrollable.

The code below will never respond with the `ASP.NET_SessionId` cookie to the client, although the code is the same as it is for the other cookie, which will completely obey either .Add/.Set/.Remove on the collection.

```
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("ASP.NET_SessionId"))
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "1st") { HttpOnly = false });
                    else
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "1st") { HttpOnly = false });


                    if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(".ASPXAUTH"))
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(new HttpCookie(".ASPXAUTH", "2nd") { HttpOnly = false });
                    else
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(".ASPXAUTH", "2nd") { HttpOnly = false });
```

Is there any reason that i am unable to return a "custom cookie" named `ASP.NET_SessionId` ?
I have removed all logic related to forms auth, so that cookie is not generated by default anymore, but it looks like i can not fake return it either.

Thanks in advance